# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a game similar to Galaga in a computer class I am in. I am having trouble with collisions and cannot get things to disappear without errors. I want to be able to have lasers disappear on collision with enemies and enemies disappear after 10 or so hits. I do not understand the error presented or how I can fix the problem.

Thanks

Code:

```
import pygame, sys, pygame.mixer
from sys import exit
import random
from pygame import *
import time
h = 700
w = 700
m = 0
h = 0
score = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
x = 400
y = 400
white = (255, 255, 255)
background = pygame.image.load('water.png')
pygame.init()

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 100
        self.velocity = 0
        self.images = pygame.image.load('speeder.png')
        self.numImages = 6
        self.cImage = 0
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx -= 8
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx += 8  
        self.x += self.speedx
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.cImage = 0
            self.y += 4
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP] and (self.cImage <= self.numImages - 1):
            self.cImage += 1
            self.y -= 10  
        if self.cImage >= 5:
            self.cImage = 5 
    def render(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.images, (self.x, self.y), (self.cImage * self.width, 0, self.width, self.height)) 
class Enemy1:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 128
    self.height = 128
    self.velocity = 0
    self.images = pygame.image.load('enemy1.png')
    self.numImages = 7
    self.cImage = 0
    self.z = 0
    self.j = 0
    self.rect = self.images.get_rect()
def update(self):
    self.j += 1
    self.speedx = 0
    self.speedy = 0
    self.y += 1
    if self.z <= 100:
        self.x += random.randint(1, 2)
    elif self.z > 100 and self.z < 200:
        self.x += random.randint(-2, -1)  
    #self.cImage += 1
    if self.z >= 200:
        self.z = 0    
    if self.j % 10 == 0:
        self.cImage += 1 
    if self.cImage == 7:
        self.cImage = 0
    self.z += random.randint(0, 5)
def render(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.images, (self.x, self.y), (self.cImage * self.width, 0, self.width, self.height))                    
class Laser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('lazer.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        self.m = 0  
    def update(self):
        self.m += 1
        if (self.m % 5) != 0 or self.m % 4 != 1:
            self.rect.y -= 13
    def kill(self):
        self.image = None
class RLaser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('lazer.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        self.m = 0  
    def update(self):
        self.m += 1
        if (self.m % 5) != 0 or self.m % 4 != 1:
            self.rect.y += 13
   class Boss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = 50
            self.height = 100
            self.velocity = 0
            self.images = pygame.image.load('boss.png')
            self.numImages = 5
            self.cImage = 0
            self.z = 0
            self.rect = self.images.get_rect()
        def update(self):
            self.speedx = 0
            self.speedy = 0
            self.y += 1
            if self.z <= 100:
                self.x += random.randint(1, 2)
            elif self.z > 100 and self.z < 200:
                self.x += random.randint(-2, -1)  
            self.cImage += 1
            if self.z >= 200:
                self.z = 0 
            if self.cImage == 5:
                self.cImage = 4
            self.z += random.randint(0, 5) 
        def render(self, screen):
            screen.blit(self.images, (self.x, self.y), (self.cImage * self.width, 0, self.width, self.height))               

pygame.init()                          
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
laser_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
#enemy1blast_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(400, 590)
boss = Boss(300, 100) 
enemy = Enemy1(100, 50)  
j = 0                 
while not done:
    j += 1
    screen.blit(background, (0, (-690 * 2) + j))
    screen.blit(background, (0, -690 + j))
    screen.blit(background, (0, j))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 690 + j))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #j += 1
    #if j % 10 == 0:
     #   enemy1blaster = Enemy1Blast()
      #  enemy1blaster.rect.x = enemy.x
       # enemy1blaster.rect.y = enemy.y
        #all_sprites_list.add(enemy1blaster)
        #enemy1blast_list.add(enemy1blaster)
    if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        m += 2
        if (m % 4) != 0:
            laser = Laser()
            laser.rect.x = (player.x + 14)
            laser.rect.y = (player.y - 6)
            all_sprites_list.add(laser)
            laser_list.add(laser)
            for laser in laser_list:
                if laser.rect.x >= enemy.rect.x or laser.rect.x <= enemy.rect.x and laser.rect.y >= enemy.rect.y or laser.rect.y <= enemy.rect.y:
                    laser.kill() 
    if pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        h += 2  
        if (h % 4) != 0:
            l = Laser()
            l.rect.x = (player.x + 61)
            l.rect.y = (player.y - 6)
            all_sprites_list.add(l)
            laser_list.add(l)
            lsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Laser.wav")
            lsound.play()
    if j % 20 == 0 and boss.y <= 700:
        bl = RLaser()
        bl2 = RLaser()
        bl.rect.x = (boss.x + 1)
        bl.rect.y = (boss.y + 50)
        bl2.rect.x = (boss.x + 19)
        bl2.rect.y = (boss.y + 50)
        all_sprites_list.add(bl)
        all_sprites_list.add(bl2)
        laser_list.add(bl)
        laser_list.add(bl2)
        blsound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Laser.wav")
        blsound.play()
        #if bool(bl) == True:
        #bl.rect.y += 26            
    all_sprites_list.update()
    #if bool(bl) == True:
        #bl.rect.y += 26
    #for laser in laser_list:
     #   if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(boss, laser):
      #      laser.kill()
       #     print "asdfasdf"

if player.y <= 200:
    player.y = 202
if player.y >= 633:
    player.y = 631
if player.x >= 623:
    player.x = 621
if player.x <= -30:
    player.x = -28   


#Collision_Detector(laser, l, boss)        
boss.render(screen)
boss.update()  
enemy.render(screen)
enemy.update()          
player.render(screen)
player.update()
boss_laser_hlist = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(boss, laser_list, False)
enemy_laser_hlist = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, laser_list, False)
for laser in enemy_laser_hlist:
    score += 1
for laser in boss_laser_hlist:
    score += 1
    print score
all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(30)
```

pygame.quit()

Comment: What line in your code is the error on?

Comment: It has aproblem with line 252 when it draws them.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mktalaga/Desktop/Canterbury 2016/Computer Tech 2/Final.py", line 252, in <module>
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 409, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None

Comment: I haven't used pygame, but it looks like `screen` is `None` by line 252.  I can't see where it would get set to `None` in your code.  Can you put a print in after the places it is mentioned in the code to see if it's getting nulled out somewhere?